# Upload Image not using erb (form) rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there is a way to upload images in rails 4 not using erb. I have my html code in quotations in my model (so that i can use it as a default for when creating a page). SO I cant put erb in the quotes, cuz if i do it'll come out as the erb code and not the actual view. (i.e. the upload image form. itll come out as the actual f.image_tag instead of the actual upload button).

So I am just seeing if there another way i could implement image uploading into the quotations that wont require erb. But, uses Rails 4.

Comment: With `html code in quotations in my model` you mean you have your HTML as a string in a variable in your controller? That is very bad practice, I believe... And I don't quite understand the rest of your question, particularly the 'not using erb': you mean using a static HTML? Or not using the rails form_for & friends tags in the erb?

Comment: what i mean is this..i have my model (sections.rb). In there is html code that creates a 'default-layout' for when creating a page. the html is in a string, yes. so you should know that if you put erb code inside a sting, it will come out as that erb code, and not what the code should bring out as a view. so yea i do not want to have to use the 'form.image_tag :image'.

Comment: i was thinking, maybe like some kind of 'clickable' class or something? i do not know for sure how to implement that without having to download a WHOLE editor gem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plain HTML code inside the string, and just want it to be displayed, you need to call .html_safe in your view, like:

```
'<div id="foo">bar</div>'.html_safe()
```

Note that normally is a bad practice: that doesn't mean it is always bad, but it means that it is always an attention point to make sure it is the best way to do it.

If you want to do image upload without using form.image_tag, you can just put that in your view and see the generated code (`Ctrl+U` in Chrome), that, in this case, will be something like:

```
<input type="file" id="something" />
```

And add that to the string. Probably some finer validation and options are added too via JS, that would be a pain to add this way - one way to be to add a script tag to the html with the code.

If, however, your string already contains code like this, and you are asking way it is not working, then you need to add an eval to the caller, e.g.:

```
eval('form.image_tag :image')
```

Not that this is an even worse smell, and it should be avoided at all costs.

Maybe it would be better to add some flags in your section.rb model, and then use that in a helper or in the view render the html; for example, a has_upload? field, and then you can do something like this:

```
if @section.has_upload?
  form.image_tag :imagem
end
```

Comment: i'll try that .html_safe, i think i may already have tried, but i will double check. And I will also check out that second part. Thanks man, no one has really answered any of my questions on here (which may be cuz they're so confusing since I am new to RoR). They usually just leave a question in a comment and thats it, or they'll vote it down/ put on hold. Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome! I was too a bit confused with your question, but hopefully these ideas will help you out. If you stumble upon a more specific question, feel free to ask again.

Comment: wait nevermind..i got it...so i (im new excuse my stupidty) would put what in the 'id' spot? like image? or what?

Comment: There should be a space, they should be separated and the same color in Sublime (depending on the Color Schema you are using). Note that this will create a simple file upload, you need to investigate further what exactly rails image_tag does behind the scenes, like custom validations and whatnot.

Comment: When you use image_tag :image, the field created has name="image" and id="image", which you will need to add if your are trying to mimic this behavior. You can get rid of the id, of course, if your not using it, but the name is used once the form is submitted to be handled on the server. Nameless fields are not submitted.

Comment: hmm okay. gotchya...imma have to look more into it i guess, cuz when i  choose an image then hit save it doesnt save it...im pretty sure that has to do with the controller not having anything about saving an image in it. or even the model's paperclip validation (which are currently commented out). I'll check it out.

Comment: which the problem is with my paperclip validations i am getting an error for some reason...i do not know why..anyways...thanks for the help man! helped a lot. ive been on a search and i finally have stepped over that.